# Javascript: Unitentional Focus Blur

Tags: javascript, html

In my endeavor to learn Javascript, I've been trying to implement a WYSIWYG code editor. Instead of implementing a content-editable `div` or a `textarea`, I took a leaf (rather, a lot of leaves) out of Ajax.org's ACE's book.

I have a listener `div` with `tabIndex` set to 0, to handle all input events. All the components of the editor, like the text area, cursor and gutter, are children to this listener. Since implementing mouse event handlers, I have been having a problem of the focus being lost on `mousedown` events. Apparently, the `blur` event is being fired even when the `mousedown` event occurs in the listener.

After commenting out certain method calls and trying to see exactly what was causing the problem, I noticed that the culprit was the `render` method. Now, I call this method after every input, so it is very strange for the focus to be lost particularly when I call it for the `mousedown` event. On commenting out the `render` method, `blur` event is not fired when there is a `mousedown` event.

Going in further, it turns out that on commenting out the part where I replace the `innerHTML` of my text container, the problem disappears. This, again, is very odd since I use the `replaceInnerHTML` function at various places in the `render` function, but the problem seems to arise only from particularly updating the text `div`.

This is the replaceInnerHTML method (which I discovered [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-than-innerhtml)):

```
function replaceInnerHTML(el, html) {
    var newEl = el.cloneNode(false);

    newEl.innerHTML = html;

    el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);

    return newEl;
}
```

And this is the update function for the text layer, on omitting which this problem does not occur:

```
TextLayer.prototype.update = function(config) {
    html = [];

    var top = config.topRow;
    var last = config.lastRow;

    for(var i=top; i<=last; i++) {
        var line = this._session.getLine(i);
        if(line) {
            html.push('<div class="line" style="height:'+this.$characterSize.height+'px;">');
            this.renderLine(html, line);
            html.push('</div>');
        }       
    }   

    this._text = replaceInnerHTML(this._text, html.join(''));
    this.setSize(config.totalWidth, config.scrollHeight);
};
```

Why would the focus get blurred only due to replacing the `innerHTML` of a particular node, and that too only when it is called in case of a `mousedown` event?

Or am I going in a completely wrong direction in trying to debug this, and this problem is due to something else?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to pimvdb, here is a fiddle reproducing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/wG4Yy/39/

The `blur` event seems to fire due to restructuring the nodes on the `mousedown` event. I do not know how to solve problem. I have tried using a document fragment instead of innerHTML, and I have also tried scheduling the update with `setTimeout`, but neither attempt worked.

What should I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce - is it correct that this fiddle reproduces the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/YVAmh/ (Clicking the span so that it gets replaced loses focus, but clicking the div does not.)

Comment: Yes, it accurately reproduces the issue. I made another fiddle to show kind of what I'm actually trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/wG4Yy/39/ (Focus is gained on pressing tab, keyboard events work. But once there is a `mousedown`, `blur` is fired and keyboard events no longer work.)

Comment: I've been fiddling around but I've not found out why it takes focus away. A (temporary?) solution is to focus manually after the browser has processed mousedown/focus events: http://jsfiddle.net/wG4Yy/41/.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying a few different things, and am now using `setTimeout` to call `TextLayer.update`. Something like this; http://jsfiddle.net/wG4Yy/42/. It works, but like you said it feels like a weak solution. Still, it works, and I really appreciate it. Could you post it as an answer instead of a comment so I can accept it? Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want an element to get focus, it seems like the you have to click on an element that stays there. If you replace it with another element, the browser is apparently not tricked into focusing that element.

What you can do is letting the browser finish its mousedown/focus etc. process, and focus the element manually afterwards. This can be accomplished with a `setTimeout(..., 0)` call: http://jsfiddle.net/wG4Yy/41/.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    wrapper.focus();
}, 0);
```